# Can't get this slider to work in Bootstrap and javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get this slider to move the photos along.  I'm thinking that it's the sizing of the divs that the photos are in.  Maybe I need to increase the size of the divs?  When I reload the page, I can see the picture for a split second, so it's gotta be the sizing in the div... Thanks.

```
index.php
<div class='row'>           
        <div class='col-md-6 col-md-push-3 standardMargin'>
            <div class='col-lg-12' id='inner'>
                 <img src='../images/comp1.jpg' name='slide' width='600' height='400' class='img-responsive'/>
            </div>
        </div>           

        <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-md-pull-6 firstCaption standardMargin'>
            <div class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 fancy standardMargin'>
                <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                <ul class='first'>
                    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
                        Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
                    </li>
                    <li>Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
                    Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
                    </li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-3  firstCaption standardMargin fancy'>
                <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                <ul class='first second'>
                    <li>Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
                    Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
                    Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
                    Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
                    Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
                    </li>

                </ul>              
            </div>      
    </div>

script.js

var image1 = new Image();
image1.src = 'mywebsite/images/comp1.jpg';
var image2 = new Image();
image2.src = 'mywebsite/images/comp2.jpg';
var image3 = new Image();
image3.src = 'mywebsite/images/comp3.jpg';
var image4 = new Image();
image4.src = 'mywebsite/images/comp4.jpg';
var image5 = new Image();
image5.src = 'mywebsite/images/comp5.jpg';
var image6 = new Image();
image6.src = 'mywebsite/images/comp6.jpg';
var image7 = new Image();
image7.src = 'mywebsite/images/comp7.jpg';
var image8 = new Image();
image8.src = 'mywebsite/images/comp8.jpg';
var image9 = new Image();
image9.src = 'mywebsite/images/comp9.jpg';

var step = 1;
function slider (){
document.images.slide.src = 'image' + step + '.src';
if (step < 9){
    step++;
}
else {
    step = 1;
}
setTimeout(slider(), 3000);
}
slider();
```

Comment: Fiddle, please... :-)

Comment: why are you creating a load of image objects (image1, image2...image9) that you then don't use?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap, make sure you're including JQuery along with the bootstrap.js file. You should not have to use your own JS to make the slider functional. Here's a working example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x500" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x500" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x500" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x500" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Notice the images are in the markup, not the JS.

Comment: The carousel is already working. It's the slider that is originally posted that's in question. I solved the problem by placing my script.js file before all other js source links in my html.